# How do I say, in TypeScript, "a component that I can call without props"?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Could you help me find the type to put for `Component` so that this examples compiles without types error?

```
import { memo } from "react";
import * as React from "react";

export function HigherOrderComponent(
    props: {
        Component: HELP_ME_FIND_THE_TYPE_I_SHOULD_PUT_HERE
    }
) {
    const { Component } = props;
    return <Component />;
}

{
    const Component = memo(() => {
        return <h1>Hello World 1</h1>
    });

    HigherOrderComponent({ Component });
}
{
    const Component = () => {
        return <h1>Hello World 1</h1>
    };

    HigherOrderComponent({ Component });
}
{

    const Component = (
        props: {
            mandatoryFoo: string;
        }
    ) => {
        const { mandatoryFoo } = props;
        return <h1>Hello World 3 {mandatoryFoo.toUpperCase()}</h1>
    };

    //@ts-expect-error
    HigherOrderComponent({ Component });

}
{

    const Component = memo((
        props: {
            mandatoryFoo: string;
        }
    ) => {
        const { mandatoryFoo } = props;
        return <h1>Hello World 3 {mandatoryFoo.toUpperCase()}</h1>
    });

    //@ts-expect-error
    HigherOrderComponent({ Component });

}

{
    const Component = memo(
        (
            props: {
                className?: string;
            }
        ) => {
            const { className } = props;
            return <h1 className={className}>Hello World 2</h1>
        }
    );

    HigherOrderComponent({ Component });
}
{
    const Component = (
        props: {
            className?: string;
        }
    ) => {
        const { className } = props;
        return <h1 className={className}>Hello World 2</h1>
    };

    HigherOrderComponent({ Component });
}

{

    class Component extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return <div></div>
        }
    }

    HigherOrderComponent({ Component });

}
{

    class Component extends React.Component<{ mandatoryFoo: string; }> {
        render() {
            return <div></div>
        }
    }

    //@ts-expect-error
    HigherOrderComponent({ Component });

}
{

    class Component extends React.Component<{ className?: string; }> {
        render() {
            return <div></div>
        }
    }

    HigherOrderComponent({ Component });

}
```

Comment: so do you want to bypass this MyComponent3 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the component type as  `React.ComponentClass<{}> | React.FunctionComponent<{}>`. It generally accepts both functional and classify components. Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component, memo } from 'react';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

export function HigherOrderComponent(
  props: {
    Component: React.ComponentClass<{}> | React.FunctionComponent<{}>
  }) {
  const { Component } = props;
  return <Component />;
}

function MyComponent1() {
  return <h1>Hello World 1</h1>;
}

function MyComponent2(props: { className?: string, children?: ReactNode }) {
  return <h1>Hello World 2</h1>;
}

const MyComponent3 = memo((
  props: {
    mandatoryFoo: string;
  }
) => {
  const { mandatoryFoo } = props;
  return <h1>Hello World 3 {mandatoryFoo.toUpperCase()}</h1>
});

class MyComponent4 extends React.Component<{}> {
  render() {
    return <>Hello World 4</>
  }
}

export default function App() {
  return (<>
    {HigherOrderComponent({ "Component": MyComponent1 })}
    {HigherOrderComponent({ "Component": MyComponent2 })}
    {HigherOrderComponent({ "Component": MyComponent3 })}//Just this line gives errors
    {HigherOrderComponent({ "Component": MyComponent4 })}
  </>)
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**UPDATE:**
As @Joseph Garrone finally found out the soultion, the props should be change to:

```
((props: {}) => ReturnType<React.FC>) | React.ComponentClass<{}>`
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but I want the third example to give a type error.

Comment: And stackblitz is not functional with types those days. If you paste your code in VSCode you'll get type error.

Comment: @JosephGarrone Sorry, answer updated. Please check it again.

Comment: Although it wasn't the right answer because it dosen't work with optional props, it helped. Thank you for taking the time to answer. I mentioned you in my updated question.

Comment: @JosephGarrone You're welcome. Happy it helps. I updated my answer to the solution you achieved finally for the subsequent references

Answer (score 2):

You can force `Component` to be a react component with `props` set as an empty object.

```
const wrap = (props : { Component : React.ComponentType<{}>}) => {
    const { Component } = props
    return <Component />
}

class L extends React.Component
{
    render() {
        return <div></div>
    }
}

const M: React.FC<{}> = () => <div></div>

const N: React.FC<{ customProp : unknown }> = props => <div></div>

class O extends React.Component<{ customProp2 : unknown }> {
    render() {
        return <div></div>
    }
}

const P = memo((
    props: {
        mandatoryFoo: string;
    }
) => {
    const { mandatoryFoo } = props;
    return <h1>Hello World 3 {mandatoryFoo.toUpperCase()}</h1>
});


wrap({ Component: L })
wrap({ Component: M })

wrap({ Component: N })
wrap({ Component: O })

wrap({ Component: P })
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry, I should have write a better test. I was hoping for a solution in the general case, when we don't know if it's a functional component or a class based component (`React.ComponentType`)... I updated my question.

Comment: @JosephGarrone got it. I've updated my answer to work with component type, thus  both types of components

Comment: As much as I wanted this to work it doesn't. The problem comes from the optional properties on the props (the `className?: string`). In your example you have no component with optional props...

Comment: Thanks you your previous answer I was able to put the peaces together. I put the answer in my updated question. If you update your answer to reflect it I will mark it as accepted.